# calling Shell from VB6 app in Windows 7 doesn't pass arguments

Tags: vb6

We inherited an older Visual Basic 6.0 application that works fine under Windows 7 using ADODB objects.

The previous coder built a .NET app to go along with the VB 6.0. The executable and .DLLs reside in the same folder.

When VB 6.0 is run, the shell command is executed.

```
Shell strPath & deDB.Cnct_AMS.ConnectionString & " " & "HCA", vbNormalFocus
```

The shell command works fine in Windows XP - however we suspect that it is not working in Windows 7. The shell does run the .NET executable but it seems to fail to pass the shell parameters to the executable's arg[] command line.

How can I fix this to work under Windows 7?

Comment: How can you tell that it's failing to pass the args? What indication do you have?

Comment: That the arg[] values are blank/null...I thought there may have been an issue or a security issue which prevents VB6.0 from passing parameters in its shell command to a .NET executable in a Windows 7 environment.

Comment: The path probably matters. What's the current path, and have you attempted it from another directory? Is UAC disabled? `d:\foo` for example will be less restrictive than `c:\program files`